# Strange ugly mixed dark and light theme in Gnome

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Today I completely removed KDE Plasma from Ubuntu and installed Gnome instead. I set Adwaita as the theme. The problem is that some parts of apps look strange, as if they still use the breeze dark theme from KDE. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Example:

[image: You can see the strange theming in Software and Gnome Tweaks]

You can see the strange theming in Software and Gnome Tweaks. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Gnome default theme would be Yaru.

Comment: This problem is present in all light themes including Yaru. The breeze dark theme was the one used in KDE, if you're talking about that.